# Jquery - Onclick: Hide parent container, show sibling container, call function to increment variable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a dynamic questionnaire that gives the illusion of each new question appearing and the next appear on answer click.

The DOM tree is:

CONTAINER
  [QUESTIONSTART
     [ANSWERS], 
   QUESTIONS
     [ANSWERS]
   ]

There is NO RIGHT ANSWER per question, each answer will need to increment a global variable that corresponds to how strong that particular trait is, then hide that question div and show the next one.  Since the jQuery onclick is in ANSWER (a child of QUESTION) I thought the code shoudl look like this...but I cannot get it to work.  All questions will be set to "display:none" by default.

```
$(".answer").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().sibling().next().css("display","block");
    $(this).parent().css("display","none");
    ++a;
});
```

So here is my question:

1. how to do this WITHOUT assigning ids to every question.  This questionaire will be 200+ questions and I want to avoid assigning an id to ever answer option, with 4 answer per 200 question that would be 800 ids...yuck! My jsfiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/Cory17255/hskngmL4/7/

Thanks for you help in advance!  I am still new to JavaScript.

EDIT: To fix typos, functionality still does not work.

Comment: `$(this).parent().next().css("display", "block");`

Answer (score 0):

You're using css() wrong. It takes 2 parameters to set.

```
$(".answer").click(function () {
  $(this).parent().Sibling().next().css("display","block");
  $(this).parent().css("display","none");
  ++a;
});
```

Comment: Updated code to reflect what you said, and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

and the `Sibling()` should be `siblings()` and this is not necessary to call with your DOM. Besides, this can be done with one chaining

```
$(".answer").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().css("display","none").next().css("display","block");
    ++a;
});
```

I think what you want can be done with getting index of the clicked `.answer` of `.questionStart` and getting a `.answer` of `.question` which has the same index.

```
$(this).index(); // will return the clicked answer's index
$(this).parent().index(); // will return the clicked question's index
```

And I guess this is some A versus B type of characteristics test?
Here's an example for this `index()` in such case.

https://jsfiddle.net/chidea/hskngmL4/14/

```
ans[$(this).parent().css("display","none").next().css("display","block").end().end().index()]++;
```

Was a mistake to leave `.index()` at the end on 9th edition of this fiddle..
Surely, this will return index and discarded if there's no variable to store.

On this 14th, `.end().end()` will end the chain selection of parent's next sibling and go back to select the `self` again. So, calling `.end().end().index()` will get the answer's index, inside it's parent div. According to your DOM in fiddle, this index value will be only 0 or 1 so be used to subscribe result array `var rst = [0,0];`. So you can make this array longer on needs answers more than 2.

Well, chain selection is only a function that returns it's targeted object which was gave with argument and can be reused for another task right after it. Almost every JQuery's function is made of it and deserved to be looked.

[Official document of chain selection](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/#chaining)

So, it's step by step. `$(this)` will select `.answer` div itself and return itself. We take this return to chain select it's parent, `.questionStart` div and change it's display css attribute with `.css(...)`. Next, select it's sibling next `.question` div with `.next()` and change it's css attribute too and go back to `.questionStart` with `.end()` and another `.end()` to go back to `.answer`div and get it's index inside `.questionStart` or `.question` div with `.index()` to use it as also an index of result array and `++` it.

Comment: How you wrote this makes more sense, but I tested it in my code in JsFiddle and it wont work.

Comment: Yup, it got some time to understand what you want. Modified again after testing with your fiddle.

Comment: I just posted the line of code you made from my JSFiddle edit to get it to do the showing and hiding.  Great work!! I really appreciate it!  Could you explain in the answer I posted why you need to use .index() though?  I understand it all but why that is needed at the end.

Comment: Sorry, it was mistake but it can be like this too. https://jsfiddle.net/chidea/hskngmL4/11/

Comment: Ok, so it had to be double `.end()` to go back to `.answer`div

Answer (score 0):

THE ANSWER: which came from Ch.Idea but I wanted to make everyone else could see the code that made it work.  What this does is hide the parent element and then show the next sibling of that parent WITHOUT having to make IDs.  I am not sure why the .index is needed at the end for it to work so hopefully Ch.Idea can respond to why it works but...it works great.

As a reminder my DOM Tree is: 
CONTAINER [QUESTIONSTART [ANSWERS], QUESTIONS [ANSWERS] ]

```
$(".className").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().css("display","none").next().css("display","block").index();
});
```

JSFiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/chidea/hskngmL4/10/